# SSH Lost After Creating L2 WiFi-to-Eth Bridge

Tags: wireless, ssh, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 and setup a Layer 2 Bridge to connect my WiFi Card in 4addr mode (ASUS036ACM) to my ethernet interface. I noticed that when adding the WiFi card to the bridge, I lose SSH and can no longer connect even though the device is still connected to my home network over WiFi. Is there a way to fix this? I tried uncommenting the `#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but that didn't help. Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` tells `sshd` to listen on all available IPs.  If you want to access SSH from any other machine, you'll want to restore this and uncomment it :D

Comment: Ah ok thank you! It's what Chat GPT recommended lol. Do you know how I could restore SSH? Even with that line commented I still am unable to connect once the wifi adapter is assigned to the bridge